# Transform scale a button to fit viewport without changing it's font size

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I need help on achieving this button scaling transition. I had a button in the bottom right corner of the viewport, when its clicked/hovered, it should scale to fit the entire viewport, but when I used `transform: scale();`, the `font-size` also changed. It is important **to use the transform property** because I want to use it in mobile, and to achieve 60fps animation in mobile I can only use transform property, which means I can't make change in width etc..

[image: Animation before]

[image: Animation after]

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: #fff;
 position: relative;
}

.wrapper button {
  border: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: .4s ease all;
  outline: none;
}

.wrapper button:hover {
 width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <button>Saving...</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

**PS : my snippet is just a dummy, not a valid code**

Comment: am not convinced why you should use transform ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif because the only way I understand to make smooth 60fps animation in mobile browser is by using css-transform property. Any better and easier suggestion will help so much

Comment: where you understand this ?

Comment: from the Great Big Book of Programming called Stack Over Flow :)
No, I already tried change the width property and it didn't work as i expected

Comment: still not convinced if there is no official thing that you can show me ;) ... an easier thing is to simple animation width/height using transition

Comment: @TemaniAfif animating properties like width and height triggers layout causing the browser to recalculate and repaint. Using transform lets the browser avoid all this extra work. [source](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/animations/animations-and-performance)

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about smoothness use `requestAnimationFrame` which runs at 60 fps (or whatever the screen's refresh rate is).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

> You should call this method whenever you're ready to update your
>   animation onscreen. This will request that your animation function be
>   called before the browser performs the next repaint. The number of
>   callbacks is usually 60 times per second, but will generally match the
>   display refresh rate in most web browsers as per W3C recommendation.

Here's an example from MDN:

```
var start = null;
var element = document.getElementById('SomeElementYouWantToAnimate');
element.style.position = 'absolute';

function step(timestamp) {
  if (!start) start = timestamp;
  var progress = timestamp - start;
  element.style.left = Math.min(progress / 10, 200) + 'px';
  if (progress < 2000) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```